# Teradata - Insert into table takes long time - problem with plan execution?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, teradata, sql-execution-plan

I want to insert data into the target table but unfortunately it takes too much time, even it is only around 800 000 records.
I think that the problem is with the execution plan/bad indexes or statistics, however, can you please look at the explain plan whether something is suspected there?

Here is the plan:

````
 This query is optimized using type 2 profile nonested_cost, profileid
 10003.
 This request is eligible for incremental planning and execution (IPE)
 but does not meet cost thresholds. The following is the static plan
 for the request.
  1) First, we lock Schema1.Target_Table in TD_MAP1
     for write on a reserved RowHash to prevent global deadlock.
  2) Next, we lock Schema1.Target_Table in TD_MAP1
     for write, we lock Schema1.Table1 in view
     Schema1.Table1_View in TD_MAP1 for access, and we lock
     Schema1.Table2 in view
     Schema1.Table3 in TD_MAP1 for access.
  3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from
     Schema1.Table2 in view
     Schema1.Table3 by way of an all-rows scan
     with a condition of ("(NOT (Schema1.Table2 in
     view Schema1.Table3.CUSTOMER_ID IS NULL
     )) AND (Schema1.Table2 in view
     Schema1.Table3.TYPE = 2.)") into Spool 3
     (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is redistributed by
     the hash code of (
     Schema1.Table2.CUSTOMER_ID) to all AMPs in
     TD_Map1.  The size of Spool 3 is estimated with high confidence to
     be 66,211 rows (66,939,321 bytes).  The estimated time for this
     step is 0.80 seconds.
  4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_Map1 from Spool 3 (Last Use) by
     way of a RowHash match scan, which is joined to
     Schema1.Table1 in view Schema1.Table1_View by way
     of a RowHash match scan with no residual conditions.  Spool 3 and
     Schema1.Table1 are joined using a single partition hash
     join, with a join condition of ("CUSTOMER_ID =
     Schema1.Table1.CUSTOMER_ID").  The result goes into
     Spool 4 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is
     redistributed by the hash code of (
    HERE IS THE LIST OF COLUMNS FROM TABLE 1 AND TABLE 2 to all AMPs in TD_Map1.
     Then we do a SORT to order Spool 4 by row hash.  The size of Spool
     4 is estimated with index join confidence to be 66,211 rows (
     73,163,155 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.11
     seconds.
  5) We execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 4 by
          way of an all-rows scan into Spool 5 (all_amps) (compressed
          columns allowed) fanned out into 33 hash join partitions,
          which is duplicated on all AMPs in TD_Map1.  The size of
          Spool 5 is estimated with index join confidence to be
          28,603,152 rows (31,635,086,112 bytes).  The estimated time
          for this step is 1.69 seconds.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from
          S.TAB_M by way of an all-rows scan with a
          condition of ("(NOT (S.TAB_M.EQUIPMENT_ID IS NULL ))
          AND (NOT (S.TAB_M.COUNTY_ID IS NULL ))")
          into Spool 6 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed) fanned
          out into 33 hash join partitions, which is built locally on
          the AMPs.  The size of Spool 6 is estimated with high
          confidence to be 120,648,009 rows (29,679,410,214 bytes).
          The estimated time for this step is 2.68 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_Map1 from Spool 6 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 5 (Last Use) by
     way of an all-rows scan.  Spool 6 and Spool 5 are joined using a
     hash join of 33 partitions, with a join condition of ("(NOT
     (SubCustomer_ID IS NULL )) AND ((NOT (ORG_ID IS NULL )) AND
     ((EQUIPMENT_ID = SubCustomer_ID) AND ((COUNTY_ID )= (ORG_ID
     (FLOAT, FORMAT '-9.99999999999999E-999')))))").  The result goes
     into Spool 7 (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed), which is
     redistributed by the hash code of (
HERE IS THE LIST OF COLUMNS FROM TABLE 1 AND TABLE 2) to all AMPs in
     TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 7 by row hash.  The
     size of Spool 7 is estimated with index join confidence to be
     88,525 rows (28,239,475 bytes).
  7) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_Map1 from Spool 7 (Last Use) by
     way of a RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 4 (Last Use)
     by way of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 7 and Spool 4 are
     right outer joined using a merge join, with a join condition of (
     "Field_1 = Field_1").  The result goes into Spool 2 (all_amps)
     (compressed columns allowed), which is built locally on the AMPs.
     The size of Spool 2 is estimated with index join confidence to be
     88,525 rows (114,639,875 bytes).  The estimated time for this step
     is 1.68 seconds.
  8) We do an all-AMPs SUM step in TD_Map1 to aggregate from Spool 2
     (Last Use) by way of an all-rows scan, grouping by field1 (HERE IS THE LIST OF COLUMNS FROM TABLE 1 AND TABLE 2 AND S.TAB_M).  Aggregate Intermediate
     Results are computed locally, then placed in Spool 11 in TD_Map1.
     The size of Spool 11 is estimated with low confidence to be 66,394
     rows (330,575,726 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
     0.23 seconds.
  9) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_Map1 from Spool 11 (Last
     Use) by way of an all-rows scan into Spool 1 (all_amps)
     (compressed columns allowed), which is redistributed by the hash
     code of ((CASE WHEN (NOT (S.TAB_M.TIME_DELIVERY IS
     NULL )) THEN (S.TAB_M.TIME_DELIVERY) WHEN (NOT
     (S.TAB_M.TIME_DELIVERY_EXP IS NULL )) THEN
     (S.TAB_M.TIME_DELIVERY_EXP) ELSE (0) END )(INTEGER)) to
     all AMPs in TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 1 by row
     hash.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with low confidence to be
     66,394 rows (85,050,714 bytes).  The estimated time for this step
     is 0.05 seconds.
 10) We do an all-AMPs MERGE step in TD_MAP1 into
     Schema1.Target_Table from Spool 1 (Last Use).
     The size is estimated with low confidence to be 66,394 rows.  The
     estimated time for this step is 4.00 seconds.
 11) We spoil the parser's dictionary cache for the table.
 12) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1.```
````

Comment: There's only one (data model) issue in your Explain, it reveals that the data type of `ORG_ID` is a VarChar and doesn't match the numeric `COUNTY_ID`. Assuming the Select runs fast and is returning only 800000 rows, there's a high probability that the PI of the target table is bad and it's a SET table, resulting in lots of *duplicate row checks*. Can you share the (P)PI of the target table and some statistics?

Comment: Thank you! I change table from set to multiset and it works fast now!

Comment: Switching to MULTISET fixes the the slow inserts, but not the root cause. Better change the PI.

Comment: I have INDEX, I don't have Primary Index. Is it required to have PI on table? If there is no PI set, then data are distributed equally on each AMP.

Comment: If there's no PI in your Create Table there are two possible results: On most systems (like yours) the default will be a NUPI on the first column, but a system might be set to NO PRIMARY INDEX as default, too. How is that existing Secondary Index defined, what's the data demographics, distinct values, max rows per value, nulls? How many rows in that table? You might implement it as PI or maybe as partitioning.

Comment: I have created this table with NO PI but default is PI on the first column. In the table there is about 4 mln rows. Can you give me advice on which column should I apply PI? Is it on the most unique column to preserve the distribution of records equally, right?

Comment: You only get NO PI if you specify "NO PRIMARY IMDEX" :-)  PI should be based on access, i.e. column(s) used most in joins (and/or WHERE). Your INDEX is a candidate, but the max number of rows per value should be not too high, e.g. < 1000.